# How can I get rid of a visual flaw in my logo. It appears to be coming from 3D effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, illustrator-effects

I'm creating a logo that is text-based. When I add the 3D Bevel and Extrude effect, it makes an odd-looking glitch on one of the letters.

This logo is something I created in Photoshop then had to mimic in Illustrator so that I can give my client a vector format of the logo (rookie mistake!). So, I had to manipulate each letter to take on the shape of the one I'd made in Photoshop. Each letter is on it's own "layer" (is that a thing in Illustrator?) so that I could space them appropriately and edit each one separately. The letter in question was stretched both length and width-wise. There are no flaws in the letter *before* I apply the 3D effect. I've tried saving different formats of the file as well as undoing and redoing the effect on that letter by itself. I thought maybe it was just an issue with Illustrator, so I opened the file on another machine and saw the same flaw. This problem is not happening to any other letters.

Here is a photo of it:
[image: Issue]

The issue is on the top curve of the "S".

And here are my settings for the effect:
[image: Settings]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator's 3D effect suffers from this often. The only real solution is to alter a field by a very small amount until all the faces are drawn.

You can change the perspective to 1 and that may fix the issue with very minimal visual alteration otherwise. If not, look at changing some other field in the 3D effect a minute amount. Be certain to double check other areas after any alteration. Fixing one issue can easily result in another issue. Illustrator's 3D effect simply suffers from this serious bug.

Comment: While I'm glad to hear it's not something I did wrong, I am SO frustrated! I've been working on it for quite a while now and can't get it to all lay nicely! I'll keep trying though. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @esposatuna I feel for you. I've been in the same boat many, many times. Wish Adobe would fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before with typefaces I install (or any shapes, really) that are visually spot-on, but contain small errors in the paths.

First, if your letter `S` is still editable type, then convert it to outlines `(ctrl+shift+O or Type>Create Outlines)`. Then use your pen tool and select the paths by holding ctrl and clicking your `S`. Look at the path near where the artifact is.

I suspect that there is a doubling up of anchors in that spot, which creates a path that doubles back on itself in such a way that the solid object (letter) doesn't show it while something following that edge (like the 3d effect) has to flip to follow it.